# Expansion of $\sin^5 \theta$ using the Complex Exponential

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How do I expand $\sin^5\theta$ using the complex exponential, in order to obtain:

$$\frac{1}{16}\sin 5\theta - \frac{5}{16}\sin 3\theta + \frac{5}{8}\sin\theta$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) formula.

$$\exp({i\theta})^n = \exp(ni
\theta)$$

$$(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))^n = \cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)$$

$$(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))^5 = \cos(5\theta) + i\sin(5\theta)$$

$$\cos^5(\theta) + 5i\cos^4(\theta)\sin(\theta) -10\cos^3(\theta)\sin^2(\theta) -10i \cos^2(\theta)\sin^3(\theta) + \cdots $$ $$5\cos(\theta)\sin^4(\theta) +i\sin^5(\theta) = \cos(5\theta) + i\sin(5\theta)$$

Equate imaginary parts:

$$5\cos^4(\theta)\sin(\theta)-10 \cos^2(\theta)\sin^3(\theta) +  \sin^5(\theta) = \sin(5\theta)$$

Solve for $\sin^5(\theta)$:

$$\sin^5(\theta) = \sin(5\theta)-5\cos^4(\theta)\sin(\theta)+10 \cos^2(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)$$

Use trigonometric identities:

$$\sin^5(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{16} (\sin(5 \theta)-5 \sin(3 \theta) + 10 \sin(\theta))$$

Comment: Those equal signs should be $\equiv$ as the given equations are true for all values of $\theta$. Otherwise it's misleading and implies that there is some $\theta$ for which the equation doesn't hold, which is not the case.

Comment: @alexqwx: $\equiv$ is most commonly used for modular equivalence. It is also sometimes to denote definition. However, there is nothing wrong with the usage of $=$ here.

Comment: @robjohn $=$ is ambiguous here, for the reason I've already given. I know that $\equiv$ is used in modular arithmetic but it's also used to denote an identity.

Is there a particular reason that you have recently been commenting on every comment of mine? Shall I do the same to you?

Comment: @alexqwx: I have rarely seen $\equiv$ used this way and I have never heard anyone else complain of $=$ being ambiguous. If I have commented on posts that you have commented on, it would be because you have targeted recent comments to a particular user and I have been reading these posts in my capacity as a moderator. I have simply commented where it seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\sin(\theta) = {e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}\over 2i}.$$ 
Use the binomial theorem.

Comment: I find this answer is better. With the help of Pascal's triangle this approach is really fun.